# If previous element is x, then return it

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to build a web-scraping tool for this page: https://www.valchov.cz/sluzby/specialni-sluzby-/

I already figured out how to get the `"Vyvěšeno"` and `"Sejmuto"` by using `previous_sibling`, but now I need to get all the divs(into one variable). I think some if statement would help.

There are sometimes 1 and sometimes up to 3 divs above.

Sample from my current array:

```
['11.\xa0veřejné zasedání zastupitelstva obce se uskuteční 21.\xa012.\xa02011 v\xa019.30\xa0v\xa0budově obecního\xa0úřadu.', 'Vyvěšeno: 13. 12. 2011', 'Sejmuto: 21. 12. 2011']
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from csv import writer

url= "https://www.valchov.cz/sluzby/specialni-sluzby-/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
sejmuto = soup.find_all("p", string=re.compile("Sejmuto:"))

with open("listings.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header= ["Name", "Name bezdiakritikyamezer" , "URL", "Zveřejněno", "Sejmuto"]
    thewriter.writerow(header)

for hhh in sejmuto:
    item1 = hhh.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.text
    itemz = hhh.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.text
    item2 = (hhh.text)
    item = [itemz, item1, item2]
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question and expected output is not that clear but assuming, that your goal is to get all the links and apply corresponding dates I would reccomend to adjust your script that way:

1. You do not need extra `re` modul instead use `css selectors`:

   ```
   soup.select('p:-soup-contains("Sejmuto")')
   ```
2. Select and iterate all `find_previous_siblings()`, check if it contains a `<a>` and write your row to csv else break the for loop and continue:

   ```
   for ps in e.find_previous('p').find_previous_siblings():
       if ps.a:
           name = ps.a.text
           url = ps.a.get('href')
           zve = e.find_previous('p').text.split(':')[-1]
           sej = e.text.split('Sejmuto')[-1].strip('.:')
           item = [name, url, zve, sej]
           thewriter.writerow(item)

       elif 'Přílohy' in ps.text:
           continue
       else:
           break
   ```

**Note** *There are some irregular and incorrect spellings / punctuation (":","." or no of these)*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url= "https://www.valchov.cz/sluzby/specialni-sluzby-/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


with open("listings.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header= ["Name", "URL", "Zveřejněno", "Sejmuto"]
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for e in soup.select('p:-soup-contains("Sejmuto")'):
        for ps in e.find_previous('p').find_previous_siblings():
            if ps.a:
                name = ps.a.text
                url = ps.a.get('href')
                zve = e.find_previous('p').text.split(':')[-1]
                sej = e.text.split('Sejmuto')[-1].strip('.:')
                item = [name, url, zve, sej]
                thewriter.writerow(item)

            elif 'Přílohy' in ps.text:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

###### Output

| Name | URL | Zveřejněno | Sejmuto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zpráva o výsledku přezkumu hospodaření Svazku obcí Boskovicko za rok 2021 | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212352-b8a6db8a6f/Zpr%C3%A1va%20o%20v%C3%BDsledku%20p%C5%99ezkumu%20hospoda%C5%99en%C3%AD%202021%20anonym.pdf?_ga=2.254591048.1500514720.1653284487-1038960091.1606374959 | 23. 5. 2022 |  |
| Návrh Závěrečného účtu Svazku obcí Boskovicko za rok 2021 | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212351-4d5044d506/n%C3%A1vrh%20Z%C3%9A%20Svazku%20obc%C3%AD%20Boskovicko%202021%20v%20pln%C3%A9m%20rozsahu.pdf?_ga=2.250537158.1500514720.1653284487-1038960091.1606374959 | 23. 5. 2022 |  |
| Zpráva z přezkumu hospodaření za rok 2021 DSO Technické služby malá Haná | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212345-6733c6733d/Zpr%C3%A1va%20o%20v%C3%BDsledku%20p%C5%99ezkoum%C3%A1n%C3%AD%20hospoda%C5%99en%C3%AD%20anonym.pdf | 23. 5. 2022 |  |
| Návrh závěrečného účtu za rok 2021 DSO Technické služby Malá Haná | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212344-6bf056bf08/n%C3%A1vrh%20z%C3%A1v%C4%9Bre%C4%8Dn%C3%A9ho%20%C3%BA%C4%8Dtu%20DSO%20v%20pln%C3%A9m%20rozsahu.pdf | 23. 5. 2022 |  |
| Příloha č. 8 - Výkaz pro hodnocení plnění rozpočtu obce Valchov v roce 2021 | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212342-85ad885ada/P%C5%99%C3%ADloha%20%C4%8D.%208_V%C3%BDkaz%20pro%20hodnocen%C3%AD%20pln%C4%9Bn%C3%AD%20rozpo%C4%8Dtu%20obec%20Valchov%20v%20roce%202021.pdf?_ga=2.213369044.1500514720.1653284487-1038960091.1606374959 | 23. 5. 2022 | 30. 6. 2022 |
| Příloha č. 7 - Příloha MŠ Vachov 2021 | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212341-c798fc7991/P%C5%99%C3%ADloha%20%C4%8D.%207_P%C5%99%C3%ADloha%20M%C5%A0%20Valchov_2021.pdf?_ga=2.213369044.1500514720.1653284487-1038960091.1606374959 | 23. 5. 2022 | 30. 6. 2022 |
| Příloha č. 6 - Rozvaha MŠ Valchov 2021 | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212340-37dd337dd5/P%C5%99%C3%ADloha%20%C4%8D.%206_Rozvah%20M%C5%A0%20Valchov_2021.pdf?_ga=2.213369044.1500514720.1653284487-1038960091.1606374959 | 23. 5. 2022 | 30. 6. 2022 |
| Příloha č. 5 - Výkaz zisku a ztráty MŠ Valchov 2021 | https://valchov.webnode.cz/_files/200212339-3e3a43e3a6/P%C5%99%C3%ADloha%20%C4%8D.%205_V%C3%BDkaz%20zisku%20a%20ztr%C3%A1ty%20M%C5%A0%20Valchov_2021.pdf?_ga=2.213369044.1500514720.1653284487-1038960091.1606374959 | 23. 5. 2022 | 30. 6. 2022 |

...